# Have you implemented an nTier architecture with your iOS App?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, architecture

I'm looking to break up an app into multiple tiers and am curious how others have tackled this before.
Have you simply created a folder for the business and data layers or have you broken up the app into multiple targets (one for BusinessEntities, BusinessLogic and DataLayer)?

Comment: What do you mean, different tiers?

Answer (score 0):

I go with folders. I have the structure of my folders reflected in the organization of the classes in Xcode, too. This works very well, I can collapse the stuff I don't need and it is out of the way.